# How to append text after a certain line number?

Tags: c++

Say I have a text file containing 10 lines. I want to move to line #5, clear everything below it, and append some new texts after that. What is the most compact way to achieve this using C++ of stream (just in case I missed some ofstream features)?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the lines after line #5, or simply insert them pushing the next ones back?

Comment: Look at this answer, it will explain a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154618/delete-a-line-in-an-ofstream-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Read N lines while writing to a second file, then write all the new text to the new file after that.

Answer (score 2):

Use IOstream to open the file and store the first five lines in an array and recreate the test file using the array and whatever other lines you want. Here is a code example:

```
    // reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  const int linesToRead = 5; //How many lines to read before stopping
  string lines [linesToRead];
  int line = 0;
  ifstream myinputfile ("example.txt");
  if (myinputfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myinputfile.good() && line<=linesToRead )
    {
      if(line<linesToRead)
      { //Stop reading at line 5
        getline (myinputfile,lines[line]);
        cout << lines[line];
      }
      line++;
    }
    myinputfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  //Begin creating new file

  const int numberOfNewLines = 7;
  string newlines[numberOfNewLines] = {"These", "are", "some", "of", "the", "new",     "lines"}; //lines to be added after the previous 5
  ofstream myoutputfile ("example.txt");
  if (myoutputfile.is_open())
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<linesToRead; i++){
        myoutputfile << lines[i] << "\n";
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<numberOfNewLines; i++){
        myoutputfile << newlines[i] << "\n";
    }
    myoutputfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";

  return 0;
}
```